# LaunchCtl Access script in library folder

Tags: launchd

I have this launchctl item which runs every day to backup some config files.   The script is located in my Dropbox folder.   It use to work.  However, since Dropbox is now located at ~/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox.   I get this error in the console:

20:19:25.033494-0500 kernel System Policy: bash (22047) deny (1) file-read-data /Users/scott/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/bin/backup-key-files.sh

Any ideas on how I can get launchctl to allow access to the script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check access of the script in:
System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Full Disk Access

give it full disk access and it should work.

[source](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118508)